# DATETIME(3) type is giving syntax error in mysql 5.5

Tags: mysql

Query:

```
ALTER TABLE `ff`.`POINTS` CHANGE COLUMN `TXN_DATE` `TXN_DATE` DATETIME(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL ;
```

Currently we have `TXN_DATE` type is `DATETIME` but I want to store time with milliseconds so i tried to alter the table but it is giving the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;  check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
>   syntax to use near '(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL' at line 2

If I will change it to `TIMESTAMP(3)`, I don't know how it will impact

Comment: Do you have a data in the same table? @pavanKant

Comment: What is `(3)`? Anyway... `ALTER TABLE POINTS
MODIFY COLUMN TXN_DATE DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL ;`

Comment: you have txn_date twice in your alter statement.- is that a typo in the question or is it what you really have?

Comment: "What is (3)? Anyway... " milliseconds @Strawberry  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html time you upgrade from your MySQL 5.1 version which you are still using if i remember correctly.

Comment: MySQL 5.6.4 and up expands fractional seconds support for TIME, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP values, with up to microseconds (6 digits) precision:To define a column that includes a fractional seconds part, use the syntax type_name(fsp)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - yep time I upgraded - but it's such a faff.

Comment: Query is working fine in v5.6 and v5.7 but not working in v5.5